# How I can pass bash variable inside python command?

Tags: linux, sockets, networking

I want to pass variable server inside python command and read the python command result portStatus variable out from command.

```
for server in `echo $dnsServers | awk -F";" '{print $1" "$2" "$3" "$4" "$5" "$6}'`
  do
    python3 -c 'import socket;
    a_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM);
    host=("$server", 53); 
    portStatus=a_socket.connect_ex(host);'
  done
echo $portStatus
```

Getting this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

Answer (score 1):

Relying on expanding the variable inside the Python statement is not a good idea since the statement need to be given as a string where shell variables can be expanded (i.e. use double quotes not single quotes) and that everything needs to be properly escaped so that the shell does not interpret things it is not supposed to. This can be very complex.

Much easier is to give the variables as an additional command line argument and then access the argument with `sys.argv`, like this:

```
for i in a b c d ; do 
    python3 -c 'import sys; print(sys.argv[1]);' $i
done
```

To get a single line value back catch the result of the python code into a shell variable:

```
for i in a b c d ; do 
    foo=`python3 -c 'import sys; print("in python: " + sys.argv[1]);' $i`
    echo "in shell: $foo"
done
```

The result from this:

```
in shell: in python: a
in shell: in python: b
in shell: in python: c
in shell: in python: d
```